# footer.php - twentysixteen child theme - social links menu to output font awesome icons

Tags: footer

what would be the proper way to implement the following mark up  in footer.php

```
<footer class="footer">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
  </ul>

  <p>This site is hosted by <a href="https://www.bluehost.com" target="_blank">Bluehost </a></p>
</footer>
```

twentysixteen has a 'Social Links Menu' menu location. Below is the code from parent footer.php

```
<?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'social' ) ) : ?>
                <nav class="social-navigation" role="navigation" aria-label="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Footer Social Links Menu', 'twentysixteen' ); ?>">
                    <?php
                        wp_nav_menu(
                            array(
                                'theme_location' => 'social',
                                'menu_class'     => 'social-links-menu',
                                'depth'          => 1,
                                'link_before'    => '<span class="screen-reader-text">',
                                'link_after'     => '</span>',
                            )
                        );
                    ?>
                </nav><!-- .social-navigation -->
            <?php endif; ?>
```

Out of curiosity I added the above code in my child theme footer.php and created a new menu using custom links and font awesome classes asin my original markup however I am getting the following output:

[image]

I haven't tried to tweak wp_nav_menu so it outputs my markup as per above. The part that I can't figure out is if I remove menu label 'github' 'codepen' 'youtube' added via custom link the whole menu disappears from the footer.

Comment: Copy "footer.php" from parent theme and keep it in child theme. Then keep your above markup in that file as your wish.

Comment: There are a few ways you could do, eg. create your own footer.php with footer-custom.php if it is used for different pages with different footer. If you want to reuse those codes in somewhere else, create a widget could help. See what kind of strategy that fits your purpose and expected result. If you means how to override original footer.php in theme, @NilambarSharma's suggestion will do. Any template in child theme will not be affected when theme is updated.

Comment: The easiest way is to use a menu of custom link on appearance > Menus, and you can add the text in a widget in the footer. There's really no reason to hard code this in.

Comment: Hi Joel, I edited my question. I am curious if I can achive the desired menu output using  twentysixteen 'Social Links Menu' feature

Comment: @simongcc I edited my question. I am having some difficulty incorporating font awesome icons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Either you should use "Widget" Or use Custom theme option plugin like this

https://wordpress.org/plugins/option-tree/

Comment: I would prefer to keep my html intact because I already have my custom css which relies on that html. does it mean I can just copy and paste my html into footer.php in my child theme? I am not understanding which of the above suggestions is the best way to go...

Comment: Hi Tanmay,I edited my question. Please take a look.